# New to JavaScript and think I need a loop for this.....?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, innerhtml

I've got a 180 character string of numbers which needed to be broken down into 6 groups, separated into 2 character figures and then sorted into ascending order.

I've done this, but it looks dirty and I'm pretty sure with my gradual improvement of understanding of JavaScript, that a neat little loop would save me a huge amount of repetition.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

var ticketString =   "011722475204365360702637497481233455758302154058881928446789061241507324334876840738576186051132437816395663800818206590104559628214294664710935667287132130687703253151692742547985".match(/.{1,2}/g);

var groupa = ticketString.slice (0,15);

groupa.sort();

var groupb = ticketString.slice (15,30);

groupb.sort();

var groupc = ticketString.slice (30,45);

groupc.sort();

var groupd = ticketString.slice(45,60);

groupd.sort();

var groupe = ticketString.slice(60,75);

groupe.sort();

var groupf = ticketString.slice(75,90);

groupf.sort();

function displayArray () {

document.getElementById('ticketOne').innerHTML = groupa;

document.getElementById('ticketTwo').innerHTML = groupb;

document.getElementById('ticketThree').innerHTML = groupc;

document.getElementById('ticketFour').innerHTML = groupd;

document.getElementById('ticketFive').innerHTML = groupe;

document.getElementById('ticketSix').innerHTML = groupf;

}
```

The outputs are placed into paragraphs for now, but I know this could be done easier than the way I have it. The function displayArray loads off the body tag.

Comment: so you need to split 180 characters into 6 groups of 15 x 2 digit numbers and then sort the groups?

Comment: @Ziki ticketString is an array of two digit numbers. Slicing an array returns an array, so sorting any of the group objects won't cause an issue.

Comment: Hi, yes, 180 characters into 6 groups of 2 digit numbers and then sorted into ascending order. The code above is really rep-heavy, so just need a nudge into getting my logic right. The above works an sits into 6 rows of numbers, but it's basic as hell and I know there is a better way to do it. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is what I think is the best solution:

```
var ticketString =   "011722475204365360702637497481233455758302154058881928446789061241507324334876840738576186051132437816395663800818206590104559628214294664710935667287132130687703253151692742547985".match(/.{1,2}/g);

var group = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 180 / 15 / 2; i++) {
    group[i] = ticketString.slice(i * 15, (i + 1) * 15);
    group[i].sort();

    document.getElementById('ticket[' + i + ']').innerHTML = group[i];
}
```

What I'm doing here is that I created a local array called group, which is in turn easier to handle within a loop than using a name like "group1" or "ticketFirst".

After that I practically did the same you did, but since I used the for loop I was able to short it down significantly.

The reason why I used i < 180 / 15 / 2 is because you're pairing them in character packs of 2.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 180 / 15 / 2; i++)
```

You ofcourse have to have an HTML like this:

```
<body>
    <p id="ticket[0]"></p>
    <p id="ticket[1]"></p>
    <p id="ticket[2]"></p>
    <p id="ticket[3]"></p>
    <p id="ticket[4]"></p>
    <p id="ticket[5]"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for this suggestion, I have followed the process, but I am receiving nothing in the HTML ticket paragraphs. The console is reading "null". What suggestions could you make?

Comment: Have you double-checked the variable names? Did you copy paste it from mine or did you adjust it to yours?

Comment: Hi, i've taken your process and adjusted it to the variables I am using or, more suitable to what I am programming. The variable use of ticket[i]; is not being picked up. I inspect the console and it is reading: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: I have also adjusted the 180 / 15 / 2 to  ticketString.length / 15 / 2

Comment: "I have a quick question also, var group = []; I assume that the variable is being defined as an array first? I am not finding much about this online." - I have just seen this in your instructions. you've created a local array called "group". Got you now.

Comment: Seems like I don't need to explain the var group = [], you changing 180 to ticketString.length was a good call. Anyway you should make sure that you spelled "ticket[]" right in both HTML and in JavaScript. If you want you can try removing the square brackets (that's these [ ] ) and just put a number there, making it like this: <p id="ticket0"></p> And for the JavaScript: document.getElementById('ticket' + i).innerHTML = group[i]; I can't be sure if that would change anything.

Comment: Hi many thanks for the help, I think you've put me on the right track with this. I'll play about this and see how I get on. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you could rename your elements from `ticketOne`, `ticketTwo` etc to `ticket1`, `ticket2` etc:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 var ticketString = "011722475204365360702637497481233455758302154058881928446789061241507324334876840738576186051132437816395663800818206590104559628214294664710935667287132130687703253151692742547985".match(/.{1,2}/g);
 for (var i=0; i<ticketString.length/15; i++) {
     var group = ticketString.slice(i*15, i*15+15);
     group.sort();
     document.getElementById('ticket'+(i+1)).innerHTML = group;
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce it to:

```
var groupArray = [];
    for(var i=0;i<100;i+=15){
    groupArray.push(ticketString.slice (i,15+i));
        groupArray[groupArray.length-1].sort();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, if you changed your 'ticket' id's to a generic 'ticket' class;

```js
var ticketString =   "011722475204365360702637497481233455758302154058881928446789061241507324334876840738576186051132437816395663800818206590104559628214294664710935667287132130687703253151692742547985".match(/.{1,2}/g);
var tickElem = document.querySelectorAll('.ticket');
var strPoint = 0;
for(var i in tickElem)
{
  var grp = ticketString.slice(strPoint, (strPoint += 15));
  grp.sort();
  tickElem[i].innerText = grp.join('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this *compact* version:

```
var start = 0;
['ticketOne', 'ticketTwo', 'ticketThree', 'ticketFour', 'ticketFive', 'ticketSix']
.forEach(function (id) {   
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = ticketString.slice(start, start += 15).sort();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>

 var ticketString ="011722475204365360702637497481233455758302154058881928446789061241507324334876840738576186051132437816395663800818206590104559628214294664710935667287132130687703253151692742547985".match(/.{1,2}/g);

 function loadTickets () {

 var ticket = [];

 for (var i = 0; i < ticketString.length / 15; i++) {

 ticket[i] = ticketString.slice(i * 15, (i + 1) * 15).sort();

 var tableCre = document.createElement("TABLE");

 tableCre.setAttribute("id","ticketTable" + i)

 document.body.appendChild(tableCre);

 document.getElementById('ticketTable' + i).innerHTML = ticket[i];

 }

 console.log(ticketString);

 console.log(ticket);

 };

</script>
```

Got it fixed, @Quikers - given you the thumbs up; as this was the thinking I had - brought the .sort() function into the ticket[i] variable to trim it a little and based on the number of arrays, I have dynamically created 6 tables that hold the strings inside them. I have to develop the tables and set them up, but I am pretty much there now. Thanks for all your help.